# Get the property's array length in JSON response in Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

My return for an API call is always a JSON if either has data or not in property as "value".
The response with some data would be like this

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "Name": "StackOverflow",
      "Type": "Online",
      "count": 123,
      "location": [
        "USA",
        "CAN",
        "ENG",
        "AUS"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and with no response it would look like this

```
{
  "value": []
}
```

I have tried using length() function on response with "value" has empty array but its returning 24 as length `length('api_response')`

How can I get the length of array elements for `value` , based on the array size I can decide what to do in next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you need to use the `Parse JSON` action with your string response.

[image: Parse JSON]

Once loaded in, you can then use the expressions I've used below to get your result.  In relation to your example, I can see it's a length of one just by looking at it.

This is the expression you need ... `length(body('Parse_JSON')?['value'])`

[image: Array]

If the array is empty, it still produces the correct result of **0**.

[image: Empty Array]

If I dummy up a few more items in the array (just by duplicating the one you have) then I get the right answer.

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "Name": "StackOverflow",
      "Type": "Online",
      "count": 123,
      "location": [
        "USA",
        "CAN",
        "ENG",
        "AUS"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "StackOverflow",
      "Type": "Online",
      "count": 123,
      "location": [
        "USA",
        "CAN",
        "ENG",
        "AUS"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "StackOverflow",
      "Type": "Online",
      "count": 123,
      "location": [
        "USA",
        "CAN",
        "ENG",
        "AUS"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: Array]

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly fine, however what if there is another JSON parsing happening in the workflow? How can I reference it when initializing variable. This 'Parse_JSON'.

Comment: You can rename that specific action so you can distinguish easily.  If you don't rename them, you'll have "Parse JSON" and "Parse JSON 2" ... you'll then be able to see in the dynamic content which one you're referring to.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I see, I am new to Logic Apps and thought the naming is just friendly names and cant be used for referencing at all, looks good now. Thanks for very clear explanation of the solution. Big Kudos !